# Problem while changing the background color of a table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the **background color** of a **table** on **`onchange`** event of a **checkbox**. My checkbox is inside my table. I have written a simple javascript code but I am unable to change the color of my table if any one can help me regarding this problem. Here is my code..

```
    function getcolor()
    {

       var color=document.getElementById("item");
        var color2=document.getElementById("item").bgColor = 'red';
        alert(color.bgColor);
        alert("its"+color2.bgColor);
    }
```

while my table has id='item'. Here is my checkbox code

```
<input type="checkbox" id='id' onchange="getcolor();"/>
```

Thanks.......

Comment: what does this function alerts?

Comment: I am checking the color of my fields here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 document.getElementById('yourId').style.backgroundColor = "Red";
```

**Edit**: This is working at my end:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getcolor()
        {

            var color=document.getElementById("item");
            var color2=document.getElementById("item").style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            alert(color.style.backgroundColor);
            alert("its"+color2.style.backgroundColor);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>
        <table border="0" align="center" id="item" style=" color:#FFF;background-color:#000066">
            <th>Some Title</th>
        </table>
    </pre> 
    <input type="checkbox" id='id' onchange="getcolor();"/>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I have used this code already i am using this code in table<pre><table border="0" align="center"  id="item" style="background-color:#000066"></pre> and my code for changing it is document.getElementById('item').style.backgroundColor = "Red";

Comment: Try the edit. It seems you have not closed the table tag and your table is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The property you want is `style.backgroundColor` not `bgColor`.

```
function getcolor() { 
    var color=document.getElementById("item"); 
    var color2=document.getElementById("item").style.backgroundColor = 'red'; 
    alert(color.style.backgroundColor); 
    alert("its"+color2); 
}
```

If you want to change different table IDs, you can use the following:

```
function getcolor(tableID) { 
    var color=document.getElementById(tableID); 
    var color2=document.getElementById(tableID).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    alert(color.style.backgroundColor); 
    alert("its"+color2); 
}
```

Then you can call it differently depending on the table ID, for example:

```
getcolor("item");
```

Comment: yes brettz9 you are absolutely right. now i am getting the color red in my second alert box color2. but color of my table having id="item" is still not getting red. Thanks for your help can you help me more

Comment: Did you copy the entire code I have above--and does your table have row and cell content? e.g., `<table id="item"><tr><td>I'm a one-cell table!</td></tr></table>` It is working for me.

Comment: brettz9  i have checked your answer in excellent. My code works now but i have only one problem i am using this code where i have multiple products in a page. when i click on checkbox a table that has been selected or deselected should be highlight but an other table is getting high light in my page...

Comment: The code above is finding a table called "item" by ID. You should only use one table with that ID. If you want to support different tables, you should use different IDs, as I've now edited the post to support.  If your issue is different from this one, you should probably file a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your code more formatted:

```
function getcolor() {
    var color=document.getElementById("item");
    var color2=document.getElementById("item").bgColor = 'red';
    alert(color.bgColor);
    alert("its"+color2.bgColor);
}
```

As noted in the answers above, what you need is

```
var color2 = document.getElementById('item').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

In the second alert, **color2** is a color already, so color2.bgColor (or rightly, color2.style.backgroundColor) is wrong.

Comment: I have also used this code function getcolor() { 
    var color=document.getElementById("item"); 
    var color2=document.getElementById("item").style.backgroundColor = 'red'; 
    alert(color.style.backgroundColor); 
    alert("its"+color2); 
}
Now it returns color red in alert box but i want to change my table color red.

Comment: Can u paste the HTML for the table?